# Testing an array of threads

Tags: java, arrays, multithreading, loops, hash

I want a class to run an array of threads. Each thread would have a chunk of passwords to test. The target password that I am looking for is new byte[]{126,126,126,126,126}

Here is my current code that needs to be modified to meet the above requirements:

```
 byte[] myPW = {33,33,33,33,33};
    byte[] myPWOriginalHashed = {0}; ;
    try {myPWOriginalHashed = SecurityHash.test(new byte[]{33,126,126,126,126});} 
 catch(Exception ex) {}
    int counter = 1;
    while (true) {
        for (int i = 33; i < 128; i++) {
            for (int j = 33; j < 128; j++) {
                for (int k = 33; k < 128; k++) {
                    for (int l = 33; l < 128; l++) {
                        for (int m = 33; m < 128; m++) {
                            myPW = new byte[]{(byte)i,(byte)j,(byte)k,(byte)l,(byte)m};
                            byte[] myPWHashed = {0};
                            try {myPWHashed = SecurityHash.test(myPW);} 
                            catch (Exception ex){
                                System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                            }
                            // See if we have a match
                            if (Arrays.equals(myPWHashed, myPWOriginalHashed) ) {
                                // We have a match
                                System.out.println(counter + " words processed");
                                throw new Exception("Done");
                            }
```

As you can see there are a lot of loops running through each byte. How can I implement a thread to contain a set of numbers to test?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one direct solution. Now this creates 96 threads, which might not be optimal. Every Thread in this case test 96*96 =  9216 numbers.

```
    byte[] myPW = {33,33,33,33,33};
    byte[] myPWOriginalHashed = {0}; ;
    try {myPWOriginalHashed = SecurityHash.test(new byte[]{33,126,126,126,126});} 
    catch(Exception ex) {}
    int counter = 1;
    while (true) {
        for (int i = 33; i < 128; i++) {
            final int iFinal = i;
            for (int j = 33; j < 128; j++) {
                final int jFinal = j;
                for (int k = 33; k < 128; k++) {
                    final int kFinal = k;

                    Thread myThread = new Thread(new Runnable() {

                        @Override
                        public void run() {
                            for (int m = 33; m < 128; m++) {
                                for (int l = 33; l < 128; l++) {
                                            myPW = new byte[] { (byte) iFinal, (byte) jFinal, (byte) kFinal, (byte) l, (byte) m };
                                            byte[] myPWHashed = { 0 };
                                            try {
                                              myPWHashed = SecurityHash.test(myPW);
                                            } catch (Exception ex) {
                                                System.out.println(ex.getLocalizedMessage());
                                            }
                                            // See if we have a match
                                            if (Arrays.equals(myPWHashed, myPWOriginalHashed)) {
                                                // We have a match
                                                System.out.println(counter + " words processed");
                                                throw new Exception("Done");
                                            }
                                        }

                                    }
                        }
                  });

                  myThread.start();

                 }
              }
          }
        }
```